# daz studio model is pink

Tags: texturing, import

I imported a daz studio model as an OBJ into blender but it became pink. I have a folder for all her skin textures but when i go *external data -> find missing files*, blender said files can't be found.

[image: can't find missing files]

Comment: pls provide blender file, thx

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the textures are either a different format or are named differently. The best way to fix this is to manually import the textures, then the pink should go away.

It's actually quite simple to debug that kind of problem. The first thing you need to do is top check if you really have the image files on your computer.

After you tried the report/find missing files in Blender, Blender will report all the files that it can't find in a pop-up like in the screenshot you posted. This popup, though, will disappear after a few seconds but you can still view the reports by changing any window to an `Info` window :

[image: the info window and some missing files report]

Here you will have a list of all the files that Blender didn't find, then you can search for the files manually on your computer and once you find them, you can redo the Find Missing Files again and point Blender to the folder where you found your textures for example mine are in this folder called `Textures_` so I double click on it and click on `Find Missing Files` :

[image]

[image]

Blender will find the textures and update their path automatically even if your textures are in a subfolder **in the condition that the name of your files matches exactly the name of the images referenced by you blend file**.

If after that, you still have missing file errors, then it means that either your files name do not match or that some of the textures are really missing. You can monitor wich files are missing in the Info window again and try to find them in a different location and redo the Find missing files process again but if you exported that model from Daz Studio, you should know where those images are.

In te case of a downloaded OBJ model, the textures usually come in a folder next to your OBJ file so you should look there first and if the names doesn't match you can just reimport the images manually in Blender for each material.